# Mocking methods in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, flux, jestjs

I have a very simple unit test that looks like this:

```
import ApiWrapper from '../../services/api_wrapper';
jest.unmock('../helper')

describe('Helper', () => {
    let Helper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        Helper = require('../helper').default;
    });

    it('calls the Api Wrapper', () => {
        Helper.help()

        expect(ApiWrapper.help).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Where Helper looks like this:

```
import ApiWrapper from '../services/api_wrapper'
class Helper {
    help() {
        ApiWrapper.help()
    }
}

export default new Helper();
```

And ApiWrapper looks like this:

```
class ApiWrapper {
  static help () {
     console.log('help!')
  }
}
export default ApiWrapper;
```

ApiWrapper.help() gets mocked by Jest so 'help!' never gets printed, yet the expectation in the test fails. This still fails if we rewrite ApiWrapper to just be a plain Javascript object like such:

```
export default {
    help: () => { console.log('help!'); }
}
```

It works, however, if we change the imports in the spec (so ApiWrapper is imported in the beforeEach), and rewrite ApiWrapper to be a Singleton class, like so:

```
class ApiWrapper {
   help() {
      console.log('help!');
   }
}();

export default new ApiWrapper();
```

What is it about Jest's mocking behavior that makes this happen?

Comment: Some more info in the thread whence this question: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1245

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you move the `require('../helper').default;` outside the `beforeEach()`?

You don't need to initialise it before every test. However, I would put `ApiWrapper.help.mockClear()` in `beforeEach()` to reset mock calls.